# Node: Spawn app without frame (chromeless)

Tags: node.js, spawn

A fairly short question

Is it possible to start an application via node and make that application chromeless (i.e. not have a window frame)?

I mean can I start this program

[image]

like this

[image]

Comment: How do you render your app ?

Comment: That's not my App, that's RetroArch

Comment: Ah ok. Try to pass `fullscreen` argument to your spawn process, or set fullscreen mode on your retroarch.cfg